# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Matrix&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Matrix’

Tags: c++, matrix, g++

I have a matrix class that have a set of functions one of them is
`Matrix operator++();`

the constructor function:

```
Matrix(int num_rows,int num_col,int initialization,double initializationValue)
{
this->num_rows=num_rows;
this->num_col=num_col;
if((num_rows*num_col)==0){values=NULL;return;}
values = new double*[num_rows];
for(int index_row=0;index_row<num_rows;index_row++)
{
    values[index_row]=new double[num_col];
    for(int index_col=0;index_col<num_col;index_col++)
    {
        switch(initialization)
        {
            case MI_ZEROS: values[index_row][index_col] =0; break;
            case MI_ONES: values[index_row][index_col]=1;break;
            case MI_EYE: values[index_row][index_col]=(index_row==index_col)? 1:0;break; //I matrix
            case MI_RAND: values[index_row][index_col]=(rand()%1000000)/1000000.0;break;
            case MI_VALUE: values[index_row][index_col]=initializationValue;break;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

the add function:

```
void Matrix::add(Matrix& m)
{
if(num_rows!=m.num_rows||num_col!=m.num_col)
  throw("Invalid Matrix dimensions for add operation");

 for(int iR=0; iR<num_rows; iR++ )
  for(int iC=0; iC<num_col; iC++)
    values[iR][iC] += m.values[iR][iC];
}
```

when i try to define it like this:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator++()
{
const double d = 1.0;
add(Matrix(num_rows, num_col, MI_VALUE, d));
return  *this;
}
```

i get this error:

> matrix.cpp:367:45: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Matrix&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Matrix’
>
> add(Matrix(num_rows, num_col, MI_VALUE, d));
>
> note:initializing argument 1 of ‘void Matrix::add(Matrix&)’
>    void Matrix::add(Matrix& m)

i don't really understand why i get this and how to fix it, as it happens a lot in many different functions, how can i fix this?

note: i am using ubuntu 16.04 and a g++ compiler.

Comment: `Matrix::operator++()` ought to return `Matrix&`.

Comment: Probably because your add function has a signature of `add(Matrix&)` and not `add(const Matrix&)` If you want to keep your original add signature, which is for lvalues objects, add a new one of type `add(Matrix&&)`

Comment: Show `add` please

Comment: If you stopped shadowing your variables, the `this->` in `this->num_rows=num_rows;` wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include the code of `add` to the post, but I can see from the error that it has signature `void Matrix::add(Matrix& m)`. Here `Matrix&` means that the object you pass must be an [l-value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). Roughly speaking, an object is l-value if it has a name, and a temporary variable doesn't.

You have to change the signature of your `add` function: its must be `add(Matrix a)` or `add(const Matrix& a)`. In first case the function receives a copy of the object. In the second case it receives a constant reference, and temporaries can bind to constant references. The latter is preferred because no unnecessary copies are made.

Never pass arguments by reference (without `const`) if you don't have intention to modify them in your function. Prefer `const Type&`.

Comment: it fixed my problem by adding const to the signature.. thanks a lot

Comment: Or, just pass by value, which is sometimes (often) actually faster and easier to reason about.

Comment: @HossamSalah You are welcome! Consider accepting my answer ('V' mark at the left) if it helped you.